# How to get the pageX and pageY of an Element without using event

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there anyway to the positioning of any element without using e.pageX and e.pageY.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afkLY/9/)

The fiddle is actually a poor attempt at what im trying to ask, but i though a visual example would be better. What i want to know is, Is it possible to find the X and Y co-ordinates of any element on the DOM by referencing using

```
 document.getElementByID('elementID');
```

or maybe

```
document.getElementsByTagName('TagName');
```

**EDIT:** Although i have used Jquery in the FIDDLE, I would like a possible solution using only JavaScript.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may use

```
document.getElementById("elementID").offsetTop;
document.getElementById("elementID").offsetLeft;
```

Refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetTop). They return the offset from the parent element. If you need the offset of the element in respect to the whole body it may get more tricky, as you will have to sum the offsets of each element in the chain.
Respectively for `.getElementsByTagName`, as each object in the DOM has these attributes.

`.getBoundingClientRect` is also [worth a look](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect).

```
var clientRectangle = document.getElementById("elementID").getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(clientRectangle.top); //or left, right, bottom
```

Comment: How can i quary elements by thier offset_y value?

Answer (score 4):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#something").click(function(e){
   var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
   //or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
   var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
   var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find almost all jquery stuff here:
http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

```
$(el).offset();
```

the same as:

```
var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

{
  top: rect.top + document.body.scrollTop,
  left: rect.left + document.body.scrollLeft
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think offset() should work.

```
$(element).offset() //will get {top:.., left:....}
```

Answer (score 2):

If Im understanding right:

**UIEvent.PageX/PageY**: relative to the document (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/pageX)

**Elem.getBoundingClientRect**: relative to viewport.(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

**Window.pageXOffset/pageYOffset**:number of pixels that the document is currently scrolled. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollX)

Based on the following description:

```
const PageX = (elem) => window.pageXOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().left
const PageY = (elem) => window.pageYOffset + elem.getBoundingClientRect().top
```